# Phabricator Making Assumptions About Environment

Tags: phabricator

I am attempting to get Phabricator running on Solaris over apache. The website is working, but all of the cli scripts are not. For example, `phd`.

The first problem, is that it is not passing arguments to the underling `manage-daemons.php` script that it invokes. Looking at the `phd` file, this does not surprise me:

```
$> cat phd

../scripts/daemon/manage_daemons.php
```

Now, given my default shell is `bash`, this isn't going to pass-through my arguments. To do this, I have modified the script:

```
#! /bin/bash
../scripts/daemon/manage_daemons.php  $*
```

This will now pass-through the arguments, but it's now failing to find transative scripts it requires via relative path:

```
./phd start
Preparing to launch daemons.
NOTE: Logs will appear in '/var/tmp/phd/log/daemons.log'.

Launching daemon "PhabricatorRepositoryPullLocalDaemon".
[2014-05-09 19:29:59] EXCEPTION: (CommandException) Command failed with error #127!
COMMAND
exec ./phd-daemon 'PhabricatorRepositoryPullLocalDaemon' --daemonize --log='/var/tmp/phd/log/daemons.log' --phd='/var/tmp/phd/pid'

STDOUT
(empty)

STDERR
./phd-daemon: line 1: launch_daemon.php: not found
 at [/XXX/XXX/libphutil/src/future/exec/ExecFuture.php:398]
  #0 ExecFuture::resolvex() called at [/XXX/XXX/phabricator/src/applications/daemon/management/PhabricatorDaemonManagementWorkflow.php:167]
  #1 PhabricatorDaemonManagementWorkflow::launchDaemon(PhabricatorRepositoryPullLocalDaemon, Array , false) called at [/XXX/XXX/phabricator/src/applications/daemon/management/PhabricatorDaemonManagementWorkflow.php:246]
  #2 PhabricatorDaemonManagementWorkflow::executeStartCommand() called at [/XXX/XXX/phabricator/src/applications/daemon/management/PhabricatorDaemonManagementStartWorkflow.php:18]
  #3 PhabricatorDaemonManagementStartWorkflow::execute(Object PhutilArgumentParser) called at [/XXX/XXX/libphutil/src/parser/argument/PhutilArgumentParser.php:396]
  #4 PhutilArgumentParser::parseWorkflowsFull(Array of size 9 starting with: { 0 => Object PhabricatorDaemonManagementListWorkflow }) called at [/XXX/XXX/libphutil/src/parser/argument/PhutilArgumentParser.php:292]
  #5 PhutilArgumentParser::parseWorkflows(Array of size 9 starting with: { 0 => Object PhabricatorDaemonManagementListWorkflow }) called at [/XXX/XXX/phabricator/scripts/daemon/manage_daemons.php:30]
```

Note I have obscured my paths with `XXX` as they give away sensitive information.

---

Now, obviously I shouldn't be modifying these scripts. This is an indication that some prerequisite is not set up properly.

It's clear to me that Phabricator is making some (bold) assumption about my setup. But I'm not quite sure what...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are supposed to be symlinks. For example, if you look at "phd" in the repository on GitHub, you can see that the file type is "symbolic link":

https://github.com/facebook/phabricator/blob/master/bin/phd

Something in your environment is incorrectly turning the symlinks into normal files. I'm not aware of any Git configuration which can cause this, although it's possible there is something. One situation where I've seen this happen is when a working copy was cloned, then copied using something like `rsync` without appropriate flags to preserve symlinks.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Turned out a sys admin scp'd the files between hosts as part of the install.